# Let $V$ be the vector space of infinite sequences of finite length. Given an example of a linear operator $T\in L(V)$ having the following properties

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be the vector space of infinite sequences of finite length. This means elements of $V$ are sequences of complex numbers $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ with the property that $\{n: a_n\neq 0\}$ is finite. Define an inner product on $V$ that
$$
\langle a, b\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\bar{b}_n,
$$
where there is only finitely many terms in the sum are non-zero.

My question is that given an example of a linear operator $T\in L(V)$ having the following properties:

(1) $T$ admits an adjoint, i.e. there exists $T^*$ so that $\langle Ta, b\rangle=\langle a, T^*b\rangle$.

(2) $T^*T$ is the identity operator on $V$.

(3) $TT^*$ is a projection but not identity operator. (i.e. $(TT^*)^2=TT^*$).

---

I try to consider that $T$ is the left-shift operator that is $T: (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)\to (a_2,a_3,\dots)$. So
$$
\langle Ta, b\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n+1}\bar{b}_n
$$
but I am not sure if this one is equal to the right shift (that means $T^*=R$ where $R: (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)\to (a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$). But there will be a issue that how to define $a_0$?

Comment: Picking a nit:  The phrase you want is "infinite sequences with finite support."  Your post is clear, though, since you defined precisely what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the left shift operator. Note that
\begin{align}
\langle L(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots) &,(b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots) \rangle \\
&= \langle (a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots),(b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots) \rangle \\
&= a_2\overline{b_1}+a_3 \overline{b_2}+a_4 \overline{b_3}+\cdots \\
&= a_10+ a_2\overline{b_1}+a_3 \overline{b_2}+a_4 \overline{b_3}+\cdots \\
&= \langle (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots), (0,b_1,b_2,\dots) \rangle.
\end{align}
So, the adjoint of $L$ is defined by
$$
L^*(b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots) = (0,b_1,b_2,\dots).
$$
Clearly:

- $LL^*$ is the identity operator,
- $L^*L$ is not the identity operator, and
- $L^*L$ is a projection: $(L^*L)(L^*L) = L^*(LL^*)L = L^*L$.

Hence, for your problem, the desired $T$ is $L^*$.

Answer (score 0):

The adjoint $R$ of your right shift $T$ is defined by $R(a_1,a_2,...)=(0,a_1,a_2,...)$. [You can verify this using definition of adjoint].Clearly, $TR=I$ and $RT(a_1,a_2,...)=R(a_2,a_3,...)=(0, a_2,a_3,...)$ so $RT \neq I$.